# Get CWD when installing over PIP

Tags: python, pip

Hello I'm trying to add a custom step to my Python3 package. What I wish for, is to execute a `make` command in a root directory of my Python package. However, when I install my package with `pip3 install .`, the `CWD` (current working directory) changes to `/tmp/pip-req-build-<something>`

Here is what I have:

```py
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    from setuptools.command.develop import develop
    from setuptools.command.install import install
    
    import subprocess, os
    
    
    class CustomInstall(install):
        def run(self):
            #subprocess.run(['make', '-C', 'c_library/']) # this doesn't work as c_library/ doesn't exist in the changed path
            subprocess.run('./getcwd.sh')
            install.run(self)
    
    setup(
        cmdclass={
            'install': CustomInstall
        },
        name='my-py-package',
        version='0.0.1',
        ....
    )
```

Now, what's interesting to me is that the `getcwd.sh` gets executed, and inside of it I have this. It also prints the TMP location.

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    SCRIPT=`realpath $0`
    SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`
    echo $SCRIPTPATH > ~/Desktop/my.log
```

Is there a way to get the path from where the `pip install .` was run?

Python 3.8.5, Ubuntu 20.04, Pip3 pip 20.0.2 from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip` (python 3.8)

Comment: Nop, no way. `pip install` works by 1st building a wheel in a **temporary directory** (and the original dir is not preserved) and then installing that wheel. If you're trying to use `CustomInstall` as a post-installation script then again, no way with `pip` and wheels. The only way to have a post-installation script is to use `python setup.py install` instead of `pip install`.

Comment: @phd Seemed like it. Thanks for your reply.